# WCF Service strange Exception from Windows 8 Machine

Tags: wcf, windows-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2008

I have a WCF Service that I am consuming in a web-application and I get strange behaviour from my Windows 8 machine:

When I compile the project from Windows 8, I get the following exception when trying to connect to the WCF Service:

> The underlying connection was
>   closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by
>   the server.

I get the same exception when I deploy it onto a Windows Server 2008.

However, if I compiled the project from Windows 7 and deploy it to the server, it works just fine.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 in both cases, although one is Premium and one is Ultimate.

After a lot of testing, it seems like when I just build and deploy the project often enough, at some point it will work, without having changed anything. It seems like the chance of getting a working project is about one in five. The Service works consistently, then, though.

If any of you have an idea what could be going on, that would be nice. If you need more info let me know.